# Are there good reasons to use Meteor in 2017?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, meteor

Meteor was supposed to revolutionize web development on node a few years back, making it easy to write compelling reactive applications. I'm not very familiar with the history of the platform, but I know that since last year most of the development effort has withdrawn and gone to work on other projects. I'm trying to decide on a framework for my next application, so I wonder if Meteor is still a viable choice for the purpose, as opposed to just using plain node+react/angular/etc. These are the pros and cons I've experienced so far:

Pros:

- Easy to prototype
- Javascript everywhere
- Publication/Subscription model is kind of neat
- Reactive

Cons:

- Performance is hard to get right using pub/sub
- Framework updates don't come as often as they used to
- Locks you in with no escape
- Less people write Meteor packages recently
- Adds a lot of overhead

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit "Locks you in with no escape" and "Adds a lot of overhead"?

Answer (score 11):

Your question is likely to get closed, so I'll chime in here super quickly:

I've been using Meteor for the past three years or so, and I've finally decided to stop using it in favor of the following stack:

- Client-side

  - React
  - Apollo
  - AWS Cognito (for user auth)
- Server-side

  - Express
  - GraphQL (Apollo implementation)

I'm moving for some of the reasons you list, mostly overhead and adding too much weight to apps that could be a lot more lightweight and simple. I'm even thinking of going serverless and just having my GraphQL endpoint powered by Lambda.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That's valuable to me. Aside from that, why would my question be closed?

Comment: @JohnSmith Because your question is subjective and not a very specific programming-related issue (e.g. why is `axios` failing, here's the error, here's my code, etc).

Comment: I see. Well if that is the case, I'll have to delete it in order to avoid cluttering. I was genuinely interested in finding an objective answer, though.

Comment: No such thing as an objective answer to a stack question. ;) Everyone has different preferences. Good luck!

Comment: @ffxsam: Very Interesting. Why are you using Express? Because you need it for GraphQL? Or does Express brings you others advantages?

Comment: Actually I believe the `graphql-server` module includes express automatically. And yes, express is needed in this case since it's a Node.js server. GraphQL needs to run on an http server.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, Meteor 1.5 is now out (just a few hours after this question was asked. You should definitly check this out. [https://blog.meteor.com/announcing-meteor-1-5-b82be66571bb](https://blog.meteor.com/announcing-meteor-1-5-b82be66571bb)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, thats valuable for me too.